# Do I need to register my android app in API console to use Geofences?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

I've tried setting up both my app and [an Android sample app](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) to use Google Play Services SDK, and I get `NoClassDefFoundError`s when I run the apps on a device. I've done and re-done [the proper steps to add the SDK as a library](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). The only thing my Googling can't answer is whether I need to get an API key through the API console to use Geofences.

Do I need an API key to use Geofences in the Google Play Services SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.

The reason I was getting NoClassDefFoundError is because of the order of export was incorrect. I had to have Android Private Libraries *above* my src folder in the Build Path, Order and Export.

It's stuff like this that makes me hate Android with the power of 1000 suns.